# Abelian ideals of Borel subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $g$ a simple Lie algebra with root space decomposition $g = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \phi} g_{\alpha}$, where $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Cartan subalgebra and $\phi$ is the root system. Let  $\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{h} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \phi^+} g_{\alpha}$ a Borel subalgebra of $g$. I want to prove that if $I$ is an abelian ideal of $\mathfrak{b}$, then $I = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in \psi} g_{\alpha}$ with $\psi \subseteq \phi^+$.

I tried this approach: let $x \in I - \mathfrak{h}$, which exists because if $I = \mathfrak{h}$ and $e_{\alpha} \in g_{\alpha}$,  $[x, e_{\alpha}] = \alpha(x)e_{\alpha} \in I$, which is a contradiction. So now it is enough to prove that $\mathfrak{h} \cap I = \left\{ 0 \right\}$. By contradiction, let $y \in \mathfrak{h} \cap I$. Then $[x, y] = 0$, which is a contradiction since $C_g(\mathfrak{h}) = \mathfrak{h}$. Is this correct?

Now, knowing that $I$ is an abelian ideal of $\mathfrak{b}$ iff $\psi$ is a subset of $\phi^{+}$ such that if $\alpha, \beta \in \psi$, then $\alpha + \beta \notin \phi^{+}$, I want to describe all the abelian ideals of $\mathfrak{b}$ in the case of $g = \mathfrak{sl}(4)$. I thought of describing them in terms of $\psi$. So I obtained 8 possible ideals, each one with a root system $\psi$ made of two roots of type  $\epsilon_i - \epsilon_j$ such that their sum does not belong to $\phi^{+}$. However I don’t think it’s totally correct to assume that the root system of each ideal has always order two. What am I missing? Is there another description of those ideals?

Comment: Just a reminder: Never say "the" Borel subalgebra (or "the" Cartan subalgebra) of a semisimple Lie algebra. There are more than one imagines. Even with the condition to contain one specific CSA, there are still many Borels. Only if you choose a set of positive roots, there is just one Borel containing the corresponding root spaces. (It is good to learn what level of choices corresponds to what.)

Comment: Thank you, I’m editing right now.

Comment: May be you still need to show that any ideal of $\mathfrak{b}$ is a direct sum of root spaces, but that does follow from the properties of $\mathfrak{h}$? I only counted seven abelian ideal of $\mathfrak{b}_+\subset\mathfrak{sl}_4$? Three (of dimensions 3,2,1) on the top rows. Their mirror images on the rightmost column. A total of five so far for the 1-dimensional abelian ideal at position $(1,4)$ is its own mirror images. Then the upper right $2\times2$-block is a 4-dimensional abelian ideal. As is its 3-dimensional subspace consisting of those with a zero at position $(2,3)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen how exactly did you compute these ideals? I would be curious to know how you manage to read them “on the matrix”